# Ether was stolen from my account - Why and how?

Tags: ether, security

I was recently the victim of a hack consisting in withdrawing me all my wallet without being able to do anything.

Basically someone paid me in ETH to my address (using my public key) and then a few minutes later I the ETH I received disappear from my wallet without leaving any trace.

Can you enlighten me on the method he uses and especially how to recover it? thank you

Answer (score 1):

If Ether was transferred out of your address, there is only two options:

1. You made the transfer yourself thinking that you were doing something else, possibly through a phishing website; or
2. You lost your private key or it was stolen.

There are many, many ways to steal or lose a private key and without you giving more details on what you did before the ether was stolen, we cannot pinpoint a cause.

You should check your address on etherscan and see at which address the ether was transferred (check the last transaction). However, only the person that controls this address could send you back the eth. If it is a scammer, it obviously will not happen.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I haven't made any transactions on any site, my account was new and I didn't give my private key or other important information about the traces at all, there is nothing,  i don't use etherscan.  I read all of yours on a post on another forum that there is a way to send a virus at the same time as crypto and then have complete control over our wallets.  What do you think ? I apologize in advance for my approximate spelling and the post in French which was overrated.

Comment: I just discovered your forum in case I did something inappropriate please do not ban

Comment: Do you know what is your address? It should look something like this 0x4b1b404b787b14293731fFcD1e9a2c0cfaF19f94 (this is a random address that I took as an example). Your wallet should show you your address. This is safe to share. Try to find your address and then edit your question to include your address.

Comment: @ProProgrammeur.D It is not possible to send a virus with crypto. What wallet did you use? In my experience most 'hacked' accounts were by a user inadvertently leaking their seed phrase, or using a fake wallet. Only use wallet from the developers page, playstore, appstore, etc. Check the site certificate. Don't worry about the deleted message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain your situation with this person who sent you ether.

Why did they send you ether? p2p trade? services rendered?
What wallet are you using? Metamask? WalletConnect? Trust Wallet?
What was their request about your agreement with this person? Did they recommend you to reinstall your wallet and re-import your keys or did they ask you to use a brand new account?

There is a catch and reason why he got access to your keys and it is most of the time, the user who has faulted. If one is careful enough to not deal with complete strangers who aren't known in crypto, you have no chance of losing funds. Too many scammers out there who pray on noobs to make mistakes and they act all nice and smart but then they rob you.

There is no way for someone to just steal your funds unless they had access to your private key or mnemonic phrase.